# Dragging functions through multiple cells with spaces in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a function that needs to grab data from 1 row at a time on another worksheet. However on the worksheet the function is on, I have extra spaces and dragging the function down causes it to iterate the number of those rows instead of one at a time.

Picture:
[image]

How do I get the behavior I want? I need to drag these functions down through ta few thousand rows, and would need it to iterate the row# on teh function automatically.

Answer (score 1):

To refer to B2 from F2, then to B3 from F9, then to B4 from F16... use `indirect` references:

```
=indirect("Filled In Responses!B"&(2+(ROW()-2)/7))
```

(I also think you are doing something inefficient with `Arrayformula` there, but that's another thing.)

Comment: Thanks! What's wrong with the array formulas? I have a sheet with a bunch of columns with this data, I need to have each day on a row vs a column, and the person's name needs to follow it for each row.

Comment: It looks repetitive, and `arrayformula` is unnecessary, since arrays auto-expand. E.g., `={A2;B2;C2}` expands to three cells.